How can I get list of files from directory in ECS Fargate container
Ive tried everything I have seen online on how to make this happen. Basically I need to get a list of files from a specific directory on the container, everything Ive seen tells me I can do this with ECS exec commands. This is the output I get from the amazon-ecs-exec-checker:
-------------------------------------------------------------
Prerequisites for check-ecs-exec.sh v0.7
-------------------------------------------------------------
  jq      | OK (/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WinGet/Links/jq)
  AWS CLI | OK (/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2/aws)

-------------------------------------------------------------
Prerequisites for the AWS CLI to use ECS Exec
-------------------------------------------------------------
  AWS CLI Version        | OK (aws-cli/2.11.7 Python/3.11.2 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off)
  Session Manager Plugin | OK (1.2.677.0)

-------------------------------------------------------------
Checks on ECS task and other resources
-------------------------------------------------------------
Region : us-east-1
Cluster: JavaRestStressTest
Task   : OBFUSCATED
-------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster Configuration  | Audit Logging Not Configured
  Can I ExecuteCommand?  | arn:aws:iam::OBFUSCATED
     ecs:ExecuteCommand: allowed
     ssm:StartSession denied?: allowed
  Task Status            | RUNNING
  Launch Type            | Fargate
  Platform Version       | 1.4.0
  Exec Enabled for Task  | OK
  Container-Level Checks |
    ----------
      Managed Agent Status
    ----------
         1. RUNNING for "restful"
    ----------
      Init Process Enabled (OBFUSCATED)
    ----------
         1. Disabled - "restful"
    ----------
      Read-Only Root Filesystem (OBFUSCATED)
    ----------
         1. Disabled - "restful"
  Task Role Permissions  | OBFUSCATED:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
     ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel: allowed
     ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel: allowed
     ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel: allowed
     ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel: allowed
  VPC Endpoints          | SKIPPED (vpc-OBFUSCATED - No additional VPC endpoints required)
  Environment Variables  | (OBFUSCATED)
       1. container "restful"
       - AWS_ACCESS_KEY: not defined
       - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: not defined
       - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: not defined

You can see that ecs:ExecuteCommand: allowed is set and Exec Enabled for Task is OK.
When I try to run the following exec command:
aws ecs execute-command \
  --cluster OBFUSCATEED\
  --task arn:aws:OBFUSCATED
  --container restful \
  --interactive \
  --command "/bin/sh -c 'ls /directory/i/want'"

I get the following error:
An error occurred (TargetNotConnectedException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: The execute command failed due to an internal error. Try again later.

Ive been struggling to find a solution to this error. I know that the directory exists because my app running on the container is verifying its writing files to the directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
NOTE:
I already added these permissions for the task role:
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:*",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


I had to make sure that the IAM user also had all the necessary read/write permissons. The permissions the documentation showed only allowed write
